# Возможно ли применить эффект jQuery UI Draggable к элементам SVG?

Tags: jquery-ui, svg, html5

Всем привет!

У меня на веб-странице есть такой `SVG` элемент:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="93mm" height="53mm">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px" rx="8" ry="8" id="myRect" class="chart" />
            <text x="20px" y="55px" font-family="Verdana" font-size="43pt" id="hello">Hello World!</text>
</svg>
```

Я пытаюсь к тексту применить эффект jQuery UI [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) с помощью такой `jQuery` строчки:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hello').draggable();
});
```

Однако, ничего не происходит... Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли применить этот эффект к элементам `SVG` графики? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что спецификации DOM для HTML и SVG частично отличаются таким образом, что это препятствует корректной работе jQuery. Ряд свойств элементов, имея одинаковые имена, несет отличное содержание, ряд свойств присутствующих в одной спецификации может отсутствовать в другой, например, свойство innerHTML отсутствует в SVG DOM, присутствуя в HTML DOM.

Поэтому в общем случае jQuery не будет работать с SVG DOM. Нужно попробовать дополнительные плагины, например, [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html), возможно что-то заработает.